# Find projection from dataset

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a dataset that I have pulled from a MaxSea 3d database.

I am trying to figure out what projection is used, so I can transform and use the data. I have tried following this guide http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24893, for a small sample of data (300k points). Firstly, the fields are named lat and lon, indicating a Geographic Coordinate System (datum), but the data given looks more like it is in a Projected Coordinate System, becuase the numbers are in 8-9 digits range.

The data on file is collected around the Faroe Islands, and if the data is in Geographic Coordinates, it should be in or around 62°N and 7°W ± a few degrees, so I can conclude that the data is not in any format where the leading digits are degrees. (not decimal degrees or DDMMSS.ss, as suggested [here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2013-June/037100.html)).

That leaves me with either a proprietary, unknown projection (possible!), or it is in a Projected Coordinate system. I keep on following the Esri guide, to figure out what Projection is used, and this is where I need help, because the Esri guides only covers the U.S.

> If the data is in the United States and shows an extent in which the coordinates to the left of the decimal are 6, 7 or 8 digits, the data is probably projected to the State Plane or UTM coordinate systems.

[image: screenshot]

Here I see that there are 9 digits (!) left to the decimal point, and when I try to add some reference data, I find that my data is outside the extent of the earth.

What would you try, I you were asked to figure out the projection of the data?

[Here is a sample of the data](https://friendpaste.com/1VH3eKfz4QAUS1KRBeNvOw) (50k points). The fields are: id, level, lat, lon, weightdepth_cmap, valuedepth_cmap, weightdepth, valuedepth. The fields of interest are `lat`, `lon`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get the projection would be to ask the provider.

Looking a bit at the data, the first column looks (Northing) like Google Map coordinates (EPSG:3857), but in centimetres.

The second one should be negative for the Faroers, but adding a false Easting at 180°West (which is around 20.000.000 metres from 0°), could lead you to your area, if your data is in centimetres.

Maybe they have taken another value for false Easting, or other ellipsoid parametres for projection.

Comment: I am currently in contact with the provider of the data, but I have not received an answer yet. I will try adding the data as centimeters, and post the results here. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like another value is used for false Easting. I will keep you posted on what I find.